# how IDEs manage to debug compiled java code

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

When I build files using `gradle` in intellij and run in debug mode I can set breakpoints and step by step debug application. I'm wondering how that is possible if sources are compiled into classes? In web development we have something called source maps, is it something like that in Java world?

Comment: You can decompile your Java code, either you can use some external tool like JDGUI or you can use some IDE plugin. I don't know Intellij-idea, but in Eclipse you can attach the sources while debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

- attach sources to the compiled Java code; if you use a build tool like gradle or maven, your IDE will generally download the sources along with the "binary jar", so you will be able to set breakpoints even in this case; otherwise you can attach sources manually (be sure to match the source and binary versions in this case!);
- IDEA 14.+ has a builtin decompiler if you don't have the sources; you can use the result of decompilation and set breakpoints.

IDEA can do point 1 and @Michal says Eclipse can, too; I suspect NetBeans allows this too. As to point 2 I only know about IDEA.

Comment: Thanks! Actually my question was dictated by that [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200206/android-studio-doesnt-highlight-line-in-debugger-when-hit-by-debugger). I'm using Android Studio to debug and I'm wondering whether it already has everything for the option 2 that you specified, any idea how to check that?

Comment: Huh, no idea... I don't do Android ;) Can't you attach sources?

Comment: Sorry, what sources? Attach here?

Comment: Ah, sorry, then I misunderstood the problem. Are you positive that this breakpoint should be hit? Are you sure that those are the correct sources you link to?

Comment: yeah, it is definitely hit because I can see variable's values. Actually, the more interesting part starts from `Update - new findings` - have you read that one?

Comment: Well, your hypothesis seems correct; however I have no idea how to solve it... Android Studio seems to be based on a pretty old IDEA version.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Maybe I'll try to launch that project with intellij IDEA and have some luck :)